# Remove a place from google

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

In the app I'm building the user is able to add a missing place on the map. The place is then available, every time he searches for that place category. For this I'm using https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place.

Now, I want to give the user the possibility to delete a place that is no longer available, or it was added by mistake.

So far, I didn't find a method to do this. If GeoDataApi.AddPlace was the method for adding a place, what would the method look like for removing a place?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can't remove a place its in hands of google based on reviews

Comment: From what i've read, places mapped in a third party app, are shown only for the user, and submitted to google as potentially new places, but google can reject them. According to google: A place can only be deleted if:

The place was added by the application that is requesting the deletion.
The place add request has not successfully passed through the Google Maps moderation process, and the place is therefore visible only to the application that added it. So I fit in the first criteria. Anyway, thank you for the answer jagapathi.